# How can I add new value in total value in JQuery calculator? for example, 2+2=4 then 4+5=9

Tags: jquery, calculator

I am trying to add value in the total value of previous equation in a jQuery calculator. For example `5 + 5 = 10` then add in `10 + 5 = 15`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var evaluated = false;
  
  $(".oprator").click(function() {
    const val = evaluated ? $(this).text() : ($(".input").val() + $(this).text())
    $(".input").val(val)
    evaluated = false;

    $("#butnplus").click(function() {
      $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butnplus").text())
    });
    
    $("#equal").click(function() {
      $(".input").val((eval($(".input").val())))
      evaluated = true;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="oprator" id="butn4">4</button>
<button class="oprator" id="butn6">6</button>
<button id="butnplus">+</button>
<button id="equal">=</button>
```

Comment: did you find my solution working?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need evaluated variable. And also you are adding click event on `butnPlus` and `equal` on every `operator` click, which is main reason.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".oprator").click(function() {
    const val = ($(".input").val() + $(this).text())
    $(".input").val(val);
    });

    $("#butnplus").click(function() {
      $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butnplus").text())
    });
    
    $("#equal").click(function() {
      $(".input").val((eval($(".input").val())));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="oprator" id="butn4">4</button>
<button class="oprator" id="butn6">6</button>
<button id="butnplus">+</button>
<button id="equal">=</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, let me know if it works :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".oprator").click(function() {
            const val = $(".input").val() + $(this).text();
            $(".input").val(val);
        });

        $("#butnplus").click(function() {
            if (!$(".input").val()) { return false; }
            $(".input").val($(".input").val() + $("#butnplus").text());
        });

        $("#equal").click(function() {
            if (!$(".input").val()) { return false; }
            $(".input").val((eval($(".input").val())))
        });

        $("#ac").click(function() {
          $(".input").val('');
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="oprator" id="butn4">4</button>
<button class="oprator" id="butn6">6</button>
<button id="butnplus">+</button>
<button id="equal">=</button>
<button id="ac">AC</button>
```

Comment: Can you tell me if I want to make new equation in this calculator after first equation answer how can I replace the first answer and add new value not concatenate.

Comment: Hello @UsamaAkram, I updated my response to do that, if it is useful for you, could you set my response as valid? Thanks :)

Comment: Dear friend, you are right but in this calculator, I want to add one more functionality that is when I want to make new value after the first answer then answers replaces with a new numbers.